# Modify table data in excel sheet by userform

Tags: excel, vba, edit

In the photo the userfrom that Im using to add and modify data into tables one I click to any items into listbox all the data will filed all the textbox [image]

But modify Button(Edit) the code is referring to columns so I want to make the code to refer to table name instead to columns

here is the code

```
Private Sub CmdUpdate_Click()

Dim zz As Range
Dim rr As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim old_name, new_name, fname, new_mr, fmr

Dim EditRow As Cells

Set editBev = Data.ListObjects("T_Beverage")


ThisWorkbook.Activate

If Me.comDepartment.Text = "" Or Me.txtItemName.Text = "" Or Me.txtPrice.Text = "" _
  Or Me.comUnit.Text = "" Then
MsgBox "Please enter data  ", vbCritical, "Inventory program "
Exit Sub
End If

Set ww = Application.WorksheetFunction


old_name = Me.TxtEditItem.Value
new_name = Me.txtItemName.Text
'===== no change in name
If new_name = old_name Then GoTo 5

fname = ww.CountIf(Data.Range("T_Food[[Item Name]]"), new_name)
fname = ww.CountIf(Data.Range("T_Beverage[[#All],[Item Name]]"), new_name)
fname = ww.CountIf(Data.Range("T_Other[[#All],[Item Name]]"), new_name)

If fname >= 1 Then: MsgBox "  This name already exists  ", vbCritical, "Inventory Program ": Exit Sub
'==========================

5 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  
'==change in data table====
With Data
.Unprotect ("0000")

If Me.comDepartment.Value = "Food" Then

For Each c In Data.Range("T_Food[[#All],[Item Name]]") 
If old_name = c Then GoTo 1
Next
1 LastRow = c.Row

.Cells(LastRow, "A").Value = Me.txtCode.Text
.Cells(LastRow, "B").Value = new_name
.Cells(LastRow, "C").Value = Me.txtCode.Text
.Cells(LastRow, "D").Value = Me.comUnit.Text
.Cells(LastRow, "E").Value = Me.txtPrice.Text '
.Cells(LastRow, "F").Value = Me.TxtSalePrice.Text
.Cells(LastRow, "H").Value = Me.comDepartment.Text

.Protect Password:=("0000")

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Me.TxtEditItem.Value = new_name
End If
If Me.comDepartment.Value = "Beverage" Then

For Each c In Data.Range("T_Beverage[[Item Name]]") 

If old_name = c Then GoTo 2
Next
2 LastRow = c.Row

.Cells(LastRow, "J").Value = Me.txtCode.Text
.Cells(LastRow, "K").Value = new_name
.Cells(LastRow, "K").Value = Me.txtCode.Text
.Cells(LastRow, "M").Value = Me.comUnit.Text
.Cells(LastRow, "N").Value = Me.txtPrice.Text '
.Cells(LastRow, "O").Value = Me.TxtSalePrice.Text
.Cells(LastRow, "Q").Value = Me.comDepartment.Text

.Protect Password:=("0000")

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Me.TxtEditItem.Value = new_name
End If
```

Comment: You run `fname = ww.CountIf(...)` 3 times but then only check the last assignment.

Comment: fname running for 3 tables (Food, Beverage, and other. each table is separate but they all together in one sheet called Data

Comment: can you please help me with this code

Comment: Is code# unique across all tables?  Or is only name unique?

Comment: Yes the code # in all the tables

Comment: Code # ---Item Name---Code---Unit---Cost Price---Selling Price----Beginning---Dep

Comment: The question was is code# unique across all 3 tables - can the same code # be found in >1 table?

Comment: Yes, in all the 3 tables same code #

Comment: Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()   'To add data into tables im using this one
    Dim cellrange As String
    Dim rowno As Integer
    Dim AddFood As ListObject
    
    Set AddFood = Data.ListObjects("T_Food")     'continue  next comment

Comment: With Data
         If Me.comDepartment = "Food" Then
      cname = Me.txtItemName.Text
      fc = ww.CountIf(Data.Range("T_Food[[Item Name]]"), cname)
       If fc >= 1 Then
       amedia = MsgBox("  This name already exists  ", vbCritical, "Inventory Program")
     Exit Sub
   End If
      Set AddedRow = AddFood.ListRows.Add()
      With AddedRow
           AddedRow.Range(1) = Me.txtCode.Text    'Code
           AddedRow.Range(2) = Me.txtItemName.Text  'name

Comment: If you need to add more code then *edit your question* and add it there (along with some context so we know what it's about)

Answer (score 1):

I would maybe do something like this:

```vb
Private Sub CmdUpdate_Click()
    
    Const PW As String = "000" 'using const for fixed values
    Dim allTables(), lo As ListObject, rw As ListRow, tName
    
    allTables = Array("T_Food", "T_Beverage", "T_Other")
    
    If Me.comDepartment.Text = "" Or Me.txtItemName.Text = "" Or _
       Me.txtPrice.Text = "" Or Me.comUnit.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter data  ", vbCritical, "Inventory program "
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    old_name = Me.TxtEditItem.Value
    new_name = Me.txtItemName.Text
    
    If new_name <> old_name Then
        'see if the new name already exists in any of the tables
        If Not AnyTableRowMatch(allTables, "Item Name", new_name) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "The new name '" & new_name & "' already exists  ", _
                   vbCritical, "Inventory Program "
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    'select the correct table
    Select Case Me.comDepartment.Value
        Case "Food": tName = "T_Food"
        Case "Beverage": tName = "T_Beverage"
        Case "Other": tName = "T_Other"
    End Select
    'find the record being edited
    Set rw = TableRowMatch(Data.ListObjects(tName), "Item Name", old_name)
    
    If Not rw Is Nothing Then
        Data.Unprotect PW
        'update the row
        rw.DataBodyRange.Value = Array(Me.txtCode.Text, new_name, _
                                    Me.txtCode.Text, Me.comUnit.Text, _
                                    Me.txtPrice.Text, Me.TxtSalePrice.Text, _
                                    Me.comDepartment.Text)
        Data.Protect Password:=PW
    Else
        MsgBox "Edited row not found!"
    End If
End Sub

'find any matching row in tables with names in `arrTableNames`
Function AnyTableRowMatch(arrTableNames, colName, colValue) As ListRow
    Dim el, rw As ListRow
    For Each el In arrTableNames
        Set rw = TableRowMatch(Data.ListObjects(el), colName, colValue)
        If Not rw Is Nothing Then
            Set AnyTableRowMatch = rw
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next el
End Function


'Find any matching row for value `colValue` in listobject `1o`, column `colName`
'  Returns Nothing if no match
Function TableRowMatch(lo As ListObject, colName, colValue) As ListRow
    Dim el, lo As ListObject, loCol As ListColumn, lr As ListRow, m
    Set loCol = lo.ListColumns(colName)
    m = Application.Match(colValue, loCol.DataBodyRange, 0)
    If Not IsError(m) Then Set TableRowMatch = lo.ListRows(m)
End Function
```

**However** for this type of use case you need to consider the whole workflow: your code can be much cleaner when considered all together - lots of opportunity for streamlining.  I would also suggest considering combining your 3 tables into a single table, with an additional "Department" column.

Comment: If I add them all together into a single table can you give me the code to filter  the department data and added data depending on the department's last code also code to filter the department  sub-category

Comment: for this one what should to add for "000"  Const PW As String = "000" 'using const for fixed values

Comment: Sorry I can’t provide the full code for that change